# Reducing the size of some pdf files

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am adding some PDF files in my android application but these files are about 100 MB. This increase my application size a lot. is there any way i can reduce the size of my application and make it memory efficient?

Answer (score 0):

1. Reduce the image size in your pdfs: this is more correlated to pdf
   than Android I think. Use something like Acrobat Reader Pro, or
   Photoshop to edit the images and make the .pdf.
2. Instead of embed the pdf file on apk, provide an external link for
   the file hosted on somewhere (onedrive, google drive...), so the
   file will be downloaded on the fly by user.
3. Compress the pdfs in some .zip file and embed this file on apk.
   Then, when the user open the app for the first time, you extract the
   pdfs on internal/SD storage. I'm not shure if this will be so
   effective due compressions reasons that depend of the type of file
   beem compressed.